# Alignment Problems in Tabularx

Tags: tables, lyx, tabularx

I have a problem a with alignment getting and the tabularx environment with a stretched table.

Currently, I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\hsize=1.75\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\hsize=.875\hsize\RaggedLeft}X}
\begin{document}
     \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{.75\textwidth}{@{\,\,}Y *{6}{Z}@{\,\,}}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
        \toprule   
        Category & Strategies & Institutional Index: \\ 
                                        & & Barclay's Event Driven Hedge Fund Index \\   
        \midrule   
        \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 0.00   \\   
                                    & TSMOM(3,3) & 0.01   \\   
        \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 0.0440 \\
        & $9^{th}$ Decile & 0.0520 \\
        & Bottom Decile & 0.1480\\
        & $2^{nd}$ Decile & 0.0455\\
        & Top Minus Bottom & 0.3340\\
        \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 0.0615   \\
        & Bottom Decile & 0.1710 \\
        & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 0.4175 \\
        & Top $30^{th}$ Percentile & 0.0730 \\
        & Mid $40^{th}$ Percentile & 0.0575 \\
        & Bottom $30^{th}$ Percentile & 0.1015 \\
        & Highest Minus Lowest ($30^{th}$ Percentile) & 0.4425 \\
        \bottomrule                              
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The table looks as follows:

[image]
When I try to compile the above code, it gives me an error saying "missing number treated as 0". Could someone give me a solution so as to help with the alignment in tabularx ?

I have looked up other threads but was not able to find as I just get this error. I am still a bit new to latex and am using lyx.

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just attached picture and added the accompanying compilable code

Comment: Don't post the code that does compile: post the code that gives the error you're seeing! :)

Comment: just edited, sorry about that. I will keep it in mind in future posts !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additional formatting-related comments:

- Use `\textsuperscript`, not math mode, to raise the strings "th" and "nd" to superscript positions. (Aside: Better still, don't raise these strings to superscript positions at all...)
- Use whitespace between groups of rows to provide visual clues as to which categories apply to which strategies.
- Let LaTeX do the tedious work of aligning numbers on their decimal markers: load the `siunitx` package and use that package's `S` column type for the third column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L S[table-format=1.4] @{}}
    \toprule
    Category & Strategies & {Institutional Index:} \\
    & & {Barclays' Event Driven} \\
    & & {Hedge Fund Index} \\
    \midrule
    Momentum  & TSMOM(1,1) & 0.00  \\
         & TSMOM(3,3) & 0.01  \\ \addlinespace
    Size & Top Decile & 0.0440 \\
         & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.0520 \\
         & Bottom Decile & 0.1480\\
         & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 0.0455\\
         & Top minus Bottom & 0.3340\\ \addlinespace
    Value& Top Decile & 0.0615   \\
         & Bottom Decile & 0.1710 \\
         & Top minus Lowest (Decile) & 0.4175 \\
         & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0.0730 \\
         & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0.0575 \\
         & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0.1015 \\
         & Highest minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0.4425 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, It looks a lot more neat now !

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r l @{} Y @{}}
    \toprule   
    Category & Strategies & Institutional Index: \\ 
    & & Barclay's Event Driven Hedge Fund Index \\   
    \midrule   
    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 0.00\phantom{00}   \\   
    & TSMOM(3,3) & 0.01\phantom{00}   \\   
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 0.0440 \\
    & $9^{th}$ Decile & 0.0520 \\
    & Bottom Decile & 0.1480\\
    & $2^{nd}$ Decile & 0.0455\\
    & Top Minus Bottom & 0.3340\\
    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 0.0615   \\
    & Bottom Decile & 0.1710 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 0.4175 \\
    & Top $30^{th}$ Percentile & 0.0730 \\
    & Mid $40^{th}$ Percentile & 0.0575 \\
    & Bottom $30^{th}$ Percentile & 0.1015 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest ($30^{th}$ Percentile) & 0.4425 \\
    \bottomrule                              
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]